# Multiple larger requests freeze on IIS

Tags: file, session, delay, freeze

We have standard MVC application with AngularJs
The app is hosted on Windows server 2012 R2 IIS 10

Application contains multiple files upload functionality, files can be uploaded in parallel.
If uploading files one by one everything is okay.
But if select several files, larger ones, so the total size of them are above 10 Mb, the requests freezes and are pending for around 5-10 minutes to proceed. The same files uploaded one by one are in few seconds.

For example, If I upload 10 files, I get 10 HttpPost requests with my files

As a temp workaround I made single request with many files in it, but I don't really like this solution, as the single request is large enough and might timeout.

I am pretty sure this is somehow related to IIS, web.config settings.
I was trying to play around with these two:

```
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="110120" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="110485760" />
```

All it does, just freezes, the whole session seems to be stuck, I can't hit F5 in the page, I cannot change the URL, basically either wait 5-10 minutes until all requests will finish, or close the tab, open new tab again with the same url and post all files one-by-one separately in few seconds.

Also one thing to note, we use Asp.Net DB session, previously we were using session in the memory and we fixed this problem with the session behavior attribute.

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

After moving asp.net session to DB, this attribute stopped working, and it did not allow to use session then, so we had to remove it and have the same issue.

At this point I am clueless, maybe there is some settings on asp.net session or maybe IIS settings, or browser (don't think so, but who knows).

If anyone had similar issue, please let me know how you solved it, or if you have any suggestions what to try, it is also very appreciated.
Also let me know if any additional information needed, I will provide it as soon as possible